# Python: sorting through a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a 2D list:

```
[['Hard', '7', '27.00'], ['David', '4', '26.00'], ['Great', '2', '25.00']]
```

I want to print it out in alphabetical order based on the first index of each list. I have a variable called `listName` which stores the information as presented above. I have tried `listName.sort()` however, it does not sort in alphabetical order. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `key` argument to `sort()`. This function will sort the elements (in your case, each element is a `list`) based on the first item (`x[0]`) of that element:

```
listName.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
```

**Note:** This will sort the lists based on an ASCII comparison (please, correct me if I'm wrong), therefore, it will put *uppercase before lowercase*. For example:

```
listName = [['Hard', '7', '27.00'], ['David', '4', '26.00'], ['Great', '2', '25.00'], ['a', '3', '123']]
listName.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
print(listName)
# [['David', '4', '26.00'], ['Great', '2', '25.00'], ['Hard', '7', '27.00'], ['a', '3', '123']]
```

Comment: Explanation: This selects the first entry of each sub-list to be used for comparison when sorting.

Comment: @Christian is there any other way to do this. I havent learned about lambdas yet

Comment: @novicecoder Why that mentality? This demonstrates the simplicity, and practical use of lambdas. Instead, **learn about them now**.

Comment: Anyways, a lambda function can be written as a normal function. So, if you have learned about functions, you can use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:

```
# The data
listName = [['Hard', '7', '27.00'], ['David', '4', '26.00'], ['Great', '2', '25.00'], ['a', '3', '123']]


# Use first element for sorting using operator.itemgetter (like x[0])
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(listName, key=itemgetter(0))


# Use a function instead of a lambda (+ case insensitive sorting)
def get(x):
    # return first element of sublist and convert to lowercase
    return x[0].lower()

sorted(listName, key=get)
```

Lambdas and function are very similar:

```
lambda x: x[0]

def get(x): return x[0]
```

The difference is that functions have a name and lambdas are anonymous (unless stored in a variable). You must not use `return` in a lambda, its behavior is always like there is one.